# How to join two streams using Kafka

Tags: java, join, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to create an application that takes incoming events and joins IMEI numbers with asset ID information which is populated in an external database. I am using Kafka Connect to source this data into a Kafka topic and then creating two streams, however it doesn't seem to be working and there is no error. I am using Avro objects.

I have rekeyed both streams so that the join can be performed using the IMEI.
The join doesn't seem to be working and I am almost sure that it is the joining element as when the streamed data comes through, it is printed to the console, just the joined data isn't.

```
    final Serde<personalInformation> assetEntryDBSpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    assetEntryDBSpecificAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

    final Serde<bornRecordReport> eventEntrySpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    eventEntrySpecificAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);


    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    //Streaming events from Kafka topic
    KStream<Long, bornRecordReport> eventEntriesStream = builder.stream(eventEntryStream, Consumed.with(stringSerde, eventEntrySpecificAvroSerde))
            .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getIMEI());

    eventEntriesStream.foreach((key,value) -> System.out.println("Event Stream: Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value));

    //Streaming Asset ID updates from asset ID topic
    KStream<Long, personalInformation> sourceAssetEntryStream = builder.stream(assetEntryDBStream, Consumed.with(stringSerde, assetEntryDBSpecificAvroSerde))
            .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getIMEI());                                       

    sourceAssetEntryStream.foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Asset Stream: Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value));

    //Joining the two streams
    KStream<Long, bornRecordPersonalInformation> joinedStreams = eventEntriesStream.join(sourceAssetEntryStream, (eventVal, assetVal) -> bornRecordPersonalInformation.newBuilder()
                .setAssetID(assetVal.getAssetID())
                .setIMEI(eventVal.getIMEI())
                .setRemoteEventUID(eventVal.getRemoteEventUID())
                .setReceivedPacketUID(eventVal.getReceivedPacketUID())
                .build(),
             JoinWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(100)),
             Joined.with(longSerde, eventEntrySpecificAvroSerde, assetEntryDBSpecificAvroSerde));

    joinedStreams.peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("Asset Association Stream: Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value));
    joinedStreams.to(joinedStreamsStream);

    Topology topology = builder.build();
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, createProperties());
    streams.start();
```

Avro Objects:

```
{
"type":"record",
    "namespace":"com.-.kafkafrontend",
"name":"personalInformation",
"fields": [
    { "name":"IMEI", "type":"long", "doc":"Unique Event ID"},
    { "name":"assetID", "type":"long", "doc":"Unique Asset IDeve"}
    ]
}
{
"type":"record",
"namespace":"com.-.kafkafrontend",
"name":"bornRecordReport",
"fields": [
    { "name":"remoteEventUID", "type":"long", "doc":"Unique Event ID"},
    { "name":"receivedPacketUID", "type":"long", "doc":"Unique Packet ID"},
    { "name":"IMEI", "type":"long", "doc":"'0' - '9'"}
    ]
}
{
"type":"record",
"namespace":"com.-.kafkafrontend",
"name":"bornRecordPersonalInformation",
"fields": [
    { "name":"remoteEventUID", "type":"long", "doc":"Unique Event ID"},
    { "name":"receivedPacketUID", "type":"long", "doc":"Unique Packet ID"},
    { "name":"IMEI", "type":"long", "doc":"'0' - '9'"},
    { "name":"assetID", "type":"long", "doc":"Unique Asset ID"}
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Cannot spot an obvious issue with the code. What are the timestamps of your records? Do they fall within a 100 second interval? It might be a good idea to set a breakpoint in `KStreamKStreamJoin`'s subclass `KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor#process()` that compute the join result (and maybe `KStreamJoinWindow`'s subclass `KStreamJoinWindowProcessor` -- this one maintains the internal store) to see what data is fed into the Join operator.

Comment: Sorry how do I find these subclasses?

Comment: I debugged to check data being fed through the operator and all is as to be expected. The data does arrive within an 100 second interval also, as I produce the data to their respective topics almost simultaneously.

Comment: At this point whilst the keys are identical and are being printed to the console, I altered the join to a left join and keep receiving a NullException but don't understand why if the keys are the same

Comment: Can you update your question and share the stacktrace?